# Create a serial port between two VMs both running Ubuntu 18.04 while using a Windows OS

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am trying to debug a kernel that was complied on one of my VMs and that is now waiting for `kgdb` as I am now trying to `socat` the other VM, but it is not working. I know both VMs are talking to each other as I have tested it using a serial port terminal. Anything helps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: To be clear, only the second VM has the "Connect to existing..." box checked, while the first VM does not, correct? Your screenshot only shows the second VM.

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: yes that is correct and when launch my vm with the//./pipe/myvm i cant find the file pipe anywhere on my  vm

Answer (score 0):

From both guest VMs if you do a `sudo dmesg | grep tty`, note the name of the COM port at the address specified in your VM settings. Mine gave me `ttyS0 at I/0 0x3f8...`. I did a `ls /dev/` to see if `ttyS0` existed, and it does.

Try `socat -dd /dev/ttyS0 pty` or whatever corresponds to the COM device given by `dmesg`.

The issue is that the path for that pipe file actually lives on the host, so the guest cannot find it. The guest sees a device.

Comment: Alright so o followed it and everything was right till i ran socat and i got a permission denied error

Comment: Run it with `sudo socat...`, sorry!

Comment: it is suppose to just stay still for a while and not output anything?

Comment: Is kgdb configured to use `ttys0`? https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/dev-tools/kgdb.html#kernel-debugger-boot-arguments

Comment: this is my gkdb config kgdboc=ttyS0,115200 kgdbwait

Comment: Socat is probably the wrong approach altogether. Perhaps try this? Refer to bullets 7 and 8. https://elinux.org/Kgdb